# Create instance of property's unknown class type at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to detect when a property's type is a class type and its constructors arguments if any. The classes will vary and cannot be hard coded. I've got a property type like below and using reflection I'm handling the properties differently depending upon determined type.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    // Process this one and instantiate its class type
    public WhateverClass Whatever
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // This one will be skipped since its not a user defined class type
    public string SomePropName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now when I reflect the properties in the class (SomeClass for ex.) I need to do something different with the property types but there are some types that are classes and they may or may not have arguments needed in the constructors but since its all determined at run time I have to reflect the constructor dynamically.

```
if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass)
{
    var propType = propertyInfo.PropertyType.UnderlyingSystemType;
    // Something like this
    var ctx = propType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, CallingConventions.Any, null, null);
    // todo: instanciate new class instance

}
```

Now is there a better way to skin this cat and if not how can I create the class when I wont know the constructor arguments?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the rationale for doing this? Its hard to say if there is a better way without knowing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Side notes: you may want to check out code and behavior of one of existing DI containers (as you seem to be building your own). Also consider possibility of `WhateverClass` to be abstract base class/interface...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - Indeed need to be clarified. My guess rationale is "I'm building DI container with property injection" OR "while all these serializes require you to register types/have paremeterless constructors mine would magically figure out everything you need and construct objects for you correctly"...

Comment: Well its for some unit testing of some converter classes in our project. The idea is to autogenerate all the properties in each class and autogenerate test values. Then invoke the conversion method and compare the source property values with teh target property values.

Comment: Does the constructor even need to run? If not, you can just bypass it by calling `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` (but your newly created object may be in an invalid state if it depends on constructor logic - every property will have its default value).

Comment: If the constructor takes 0 arguments then its acceptable to not create an instance and leave the property value as a null

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know any/all constructors for an object, there is a "`GetConstructors`" method that returns an array of constructors for the class:

```
propType.GetConstructors();
```

Ex:

**classes**

```
public class PropertyClass
{
    public PropertyClass()
    {
        Value = "default";
    }

    public PropertyClass(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; private set; }
}

public class WhateverClass
{
    public PropertyClass Property { get; set; }   
}
```

...

**usage**

```
var propertyInstances = GeneratePropertyForEachConstructor(typeof(WhateverClass), "Property").Cast<PropertyClass>();
foreach (PropertyClass propertyInstance in propertyInstances)
{
    Console.WriteLine("value: {0}", propertyInstance.Value);
}
```

...

**methods:**

```
public List<object> GeneratePropertyForEachConstructor(Type type, string propertyName)
{
    var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    return GeneratePropertyForEachConstructor(type, propertyInfo);
}

public List<object> GeneratePropertyForEachConstructor(Type type, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    List<object> results = new List<object>();
    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass)
    {
        var propType = propertyInfo.PropertyType.UnderlyingSystemType;
        var constructors = propType.GetConstructors();
        foreach (ConstructorInfo constructorInfo in constructors)
        {
            var parameterInfo = constructorInfo.GetParameters();
            var constructorParams = new List<object>();
            foreach (ParameterInfo constructorParam in parameterInfo)
            {
                object value = constructorParam.HasDefaultValue
                                   ? constructorParam.DefaultValue
                                   : constructorParam.ParameterType.IsValueType
                                         ? Activator.CreateInstance(constructorParam.ParameterType)
                                         : null;
                constructorParams.Add(value);
            }
            results.Add(constructorInfo.Invoke(constructorParams.ToArray()));
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

**output**

> value: default
>
> value:

in this case we can see that it looped through both of the constructors and passed in the default value for string for the constructor that has a string parameter.

Comment: I believe this fails if the class doesn't have a property-less constructor signature.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't understand his paragraph

Comment: Yea Im doing this at the top level to get the converters argument class and return class types and yes it does fail when the constructor requires arguments. This is my problem

Comment: I think the method in part two is going to be your best bet. Of course, if this doesn't work or you don't feel like screwing with it, you may want to consider using a library like "Rhino Mocks" to create "Stubs" of your classes (or some other testing utility that does this).

Comment: @skeryl, I think the second code block is my best bet. Thanks. I'll work it and see if I can make it do what I need. I wont know "PropertyClass" in advance so not sure that will work in this line
    var propertyClasses = new List<PropertyClass>();

Comment: Let me know if it works out for you. I have updated the code to be more generalized and provided an example of how it might be used.